# How to prevent a product from being added to the cart twice

Tags: reactjs, filter, state, product

so I'm making a wishlist using it -- [enter link description here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/react-use-wishlist) . Everything is normal, the toggle function I created is working. If there is no item in the wishlist, it adds it, and if there is, it removes it. But there is such a problem. The product is added twice, one product appears twice in the wishlist. What could this be?

**I added sandbox project link -- [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Narmin131/ghjk/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clir9022j007u356pcrprp34u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clir9022j007u356pcrprp34u%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clir9022j007u356pcrprp34u%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clir92g4u015c356pdnu7jlaa%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clir91g8a00qt356puwcib62t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clir929ei012n356pj0ior15i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clir929o50013g3gb3augbgue%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clir92g4u015c356pdnu7jlaa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fwishlist%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A44.609375%257D)**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { AiFillHeart, AiOutlineHeart } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { useWishlist } from 'react-use-wishlist';

const BtnWishlist = ({ restaurant }) => {


    const { addWishlistItem, items, removeWishlistItem } = useWishlist();


    const btnForWishlist = (product) => {
        const a = items.find((b) => b.id === product.id);
        console.log(a);
        console.log(product);
        if (a) {
            removeWishlistItem(a.id)
            console.log('remove')
        } else {
            addWishlistItem(product)
            console.log('elave')
            console.log(items);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button className='btn btn-success m-2' onClick={() => btnForWishlist(restaurant)}>
                {
                    items.find((b) => b.id === restaurant.id) ? <AiFillHeart /> : <AiOutlineHeart />
                }
            </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default BtnWishlist

import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import BtnWishlist from './BtnWishlist';


const SingleCard = ({ restaurant }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="card" style={{ width: '100%', height: "100%" }}>
                    <img src={restaurant.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{ height: '300px', objectFit: "cover" }} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{restaurant.title}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{restaurant.description}</p>
                        <Link to={`/product/${restaurant.id}`} className="btn btn-primary m-2">More info - {restaurant.id}</Link>
                         <BtnWishlist restaurant={restaurant}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default SingleCard


import React from 'react'
import { useWishlist } from 'react-use-wishlist'
import SingleCard from '../components/SingleCard';
const Wishlist = () => {
    const {
        isWishlistEmpty,
        totalWishlistItems,
        items,
        removeWishlistItem,
        emptyWishlist
    } = useWishlist();
    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {
                            items.map((item, index) => {
                                return <SingleCard restaurant={item} />
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={()=>emptyWishlist()}>Clear All Wishlist</button>
            </section>

        </>
    )
}

export default Wishlist
```

Comment: Could you add the necessary css for the related components. Also can you create a codesandbox minimal reproducible sample and share the link here ?

Comment: I found what the problem is, there is a bug in the package itself, the products are listed twice. How can I prevent the same product from appearing twice? Also sandbox link is above

Comment: @PashaMammadov Please provide the link name instead of "enter link description here" and update your OP instead of posting new details in comments which won't be read by everybody.